# SAP SuccessFactors oData API. FODepartment Entity not found

Tags: sap-successfactors

This was working up until recently but now we get the following error message:

> Entity FODepartment is not found. Please check the entity in Admin Center > OData API Data Dictionary or contact your system administrator."\n}\n}\n},Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'", "failureType": "UserError"

Has something changed in SAP? I don't have access to the Data Dictionary to check at the moment.

```
https://api2.successfactors.eu/odata/v2/FOBusinessUnit?$format=json&$select=externalCode&$top=3
```

Comment: at list you should give a service name if it is standard, nobody can guess what are you doing

Comment: Apologies. Request added to original question.